# AVScreenShack example fails to save file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, avfoundation

I am trying to get Apple's [AVScreenShack example project](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/AVScreenShack/Introduction/Intro.html) running on OS X 10.8.2.

When I run the application and trigger the recording (calling `startRecording`), a strange sequence of events follows:

- The application continues to use ~40% CPU (presumably necessary to display the video preview in the application window)
- The delegate method `captureOutput:didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:` is **never called**

When I trigger `stopRecording`:

- The application continues to use ~40% CPU
- The "about to stop" `NSLog` call shows that the `captureMovieFileOutput` object carries a valid file URL (pointing to a temporary file on the desktop)
- The delegate method `captureOutput:didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:fromConnections:error:` is **never called**
- No file is created on the desktop, even after several minutes

I see no errors in the output console. Is there some way I can effectively debug this further?

The relevant code follows. I haven't modified it (but have omitted unnecessary portions of it here).

```
- (BOOL)createCaptureSession:(NSError **)outError
{
    NSLog(@"createCaptureSession start");

    /* Create a capture session. */
    self.captureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // ...

    /* Add the main display as a capture input. */
    display = CGMainDisplayID();
    self.captureScreenInput = [[AVCaptureScreenInput alloc]
                               initWithDisplayID:display];
    if ([self.captureSession canAddInput:self.captureScreenInput]) {
        [self.captureSession addInput:self.captureScreenInput];
    } else {
        return NO;
    }

    /* Add a movie file output + delegate. */
    captureMovieFileOutput = [[AVCaptureMovieFileOutput alloc] init];
    [captureMovieFileOutput setDelegate:self];
    if ([self.captureSession canAddOutput:captureMovieFileOutput]) {
        [self.captureSession addOutput:captureMovieFileOutput];
    } else {
        return NO;
    }

    /* Register for notifications of errors during the capture session so we
       can display an alert. */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(captureSessionRuntimeErrorDidOccur:)
     name:AVCaptureSessionRuntimeErrorNotification
     object:self.captureSession];

    NSLog(@"createCaptureSession finish w/o errors");

    return YES;
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput
didStartRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
      fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections {
    NSLog(@"starting output");
    NSLog(@"%@", captureMovieFileOutput.outputFileURL);
}


/* Informs the delegate when all pending data has been written to the output file. */
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureFileOutput *)captureOutput didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAtURL:(NSURL *)outputFileURL fromConnections:(NSArray *)connections error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFinish");

    if (error) 
    {
        [self presentError:error];
        return;
    }

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:outputFileURL];
}

- (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *)aController
{
    [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];

    NSLog(@"about to start running the session %@", self.captureSession);
    /* Start the capture session running. */
    [self.captureSession startRunning];
}

/* Called when the user presses the 'Start' button to start a recording. */
- (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"startRecording");

    char *tempNameBytes = tempnam([[@"~/Desktop/" stringByStandardizingPath]
                                   fileSystemRepresentation], "AVScreenShack_");
    NSString *tempName = [[NSString alloc]
                          initWithBytesNoCopy:tempNameBytes
                          length:strlen(tempNameBytes)
                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                          freeWhenDone:YES];

    /* Starts recording to a given URL. */
    [captureMovieFileOutput
     startRecordingToOutputFileURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[tempName stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"mov"]]
     recordingDelegate:self];
}

/* Called when the user presses the 'Stop' button to stop a recording. */
- (IBAction)stopRecording:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"about to stop from URL: %@", captureMovieFileOutput.outputFileURL);

    [captureMovieFileOutput stopRecording];
}

/* Called when the document is closed. */
- (void)close
{
    NSLog(@"about to stop from URL: %@", captureMovieFileOutput.outputFileURL);

    /* Stop the capture session running. */
    [self.captureSession stopRunning];

    [super close];
}
```

The log output from the above program follows. Notice that the "didFinish" log call was never made, nor was "starting output."

```
2013-04-20 16:00:01.908 AVScreenShack[8950:303] createCaptureSession start
2013-04-20 16:00:01.912 AVScreenShack[8950:303] createCaptureSession finish w/o errors
2013-04-20 16:00:02.131 AVScreenShack[8950:303] about to start running the session <AVCaptureSession: 0x100618e70 [AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh]>
2013-04-20 16:00:10.936 AVScreenShack[8950:303] startRecording
2013-04-20 16:00:10.936 AVScreenShack[8950:303] Minimum Frame Duration: 0.066667, Crop Rect: {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Scale Factor: 1.000000, Capture Mouse Clicks: No, Capture Mouse Cursor: Yes, Remove Duplicate Frames: Yes
2013-04-20 16:00:15.648 AVScreenShack[8950:303] about to stop from URL: file://localhost/Users/jon/Desktop/AVScreenShack_Y2DUaA.mov
```

Comment: Which is getting called first - the 'createCaptureSession` method, or the 'windowControllerDidLoadNib` method? Maybe logging this will help. Perhaps your issue is that the capture session is not running because it cannot run before it is allocated (just a thought)

Comment: Ah, I should've mentioned—I added logging statements into the code to check this. On every launch, `createCaptureSession` is called first. (It's called directly from the class's `init` method.)

Comment: Hmm. And the method for starting the running of the capture session is for sure called as well?

Comment: I've updated the code to include the logging calls and posted the output log as well. The session is definitely started without a problem, but it looks like the output never gets started—none of the delegate methods are called. This is despite the fact that the movie file output is registered without error in `createCaptureSession`.